# Unable to clone thread - Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

To my understanding, Following code should generate 4 clones of the local `ProcessingThread` running, producing an output:

```
processing 0
processing 1
processing 2
processing 3
```

However when I try to run this program I am getting :

> java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

```
 public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test o = new Test();
        try {
            o.process(o.new ProcessingThread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.err.println("processing " + index);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void process(ProcessingThread template) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // Try run 4 parallel processing threads from the supplied template...
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ProcessingThread thread = (ProcessingThread) template.clone();
            thread.setIndex(i);
            thread.start();
        }
        // ...
    }

    public class ProcessingThread extends Thread implements Cloneable {
        int index;

        public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return super.clone();
        }

        public void setIndex(int i) {
            index = i;
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me understand this ? and also how to rectify this problem

Comment: What do you want to achieve by cloning a thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread` is not cloneable. Calling `super.clone()` ends up throwing `CloneNotSupportedException` because of this.

Threads can't be cloned because, well, that would be a really bad idea. What if the thread was already running, and had grabbed a condition variable... should both the original thread and the clone have a lock on the same variable?

It seems like what you're trying to do is create multiple instances of a worker thread subprogram. An easy way to do this if the underlying subprogram doesn't have any per-instance mutable state is to pass in a `Runnable` instead, and create (multiple) threads from that. Really, though, depending on your precise use case you might get more mileage out of something like `ExecutorService`, which may be very similar to what you're trying to (re)implement.

Comment: This is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 11):

Just look into the source code of `Thread` class:

```
/**
 * Throws CloneNotSupportedException as a Thread can not be meaningfully
 * cloned. Construct a new Thread instead.
 *
 * @throws  CloneNotSupportedException
 *          always
 */
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
}
```

Cloning thread just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the Thread class always throws that exception when calling clone.  Since you are just calling the Thread's clone method instead of implementing your own, it's always going to throw that exception.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#clone()

Comment: ... of course, the *worst possible* way to resolve this problem would be to try to implement `ProcessingThread.clone()` in a way which doesn't try to execute `Thread.clone()`. The exception is there for your benefit!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using clone() you want to use a Function, or in this case, a lambda to create your tasks.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test o = new Test();
        o.process(ProcessingThread::new);
    }

    public void process(TaskBuilder template) {
        // Try run 4 parallel processing threads from the supplied template...
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            new Thread(template.build(this, i)).start();
        }
        // ...
    }

    interface TaskBuilder {
        Runnable build(Test t, int index);
    }

    static class ProcessingThread implements Runnable {
        final int index;
        private final Test test;

        public ProcessingThread(Test test, int index) {
            this.test = test;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(test + " processing " + index);
        }
    }
}
```

However, a simpler way of having N tasks in different using a template is to use a parallel stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0, 4).parallel()
            .forEach(index -> System.out.println("processing " + index));
}
```

prints

```
processing 2
processing 3
processing 0
processing 1
```

as there is no guarantee as to the order the tasks are processed.